# A nice interesting presentation

Tags: templates

How do I get a format like the one used on [this site](https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/DEProj/sp09/NateCurrier/NateDiffeqProject.pdf)? 
I've already seen it in some other articles, but I do not know if it's a beamer template maybe.

Comment: Looks like `pdfscreen`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you view the document properties (most pdf viewers have a menu option for that) you will see it is made with latex and the pdfscreen class.